# How to change animator parameters on an NPC object (through c# script)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

I am trying to get the animations to play correctly on an enemy in a top down 2D game, but I can't find the right code to change the animator float parameters on my blend tree.

For the player controlled character I used the "`Input.GetAxis`" and then "`SetFloat`" etc to set them and it works fine.

What's the code to get the float x,y (from -1 to 1) values of the movement of my object and set them to my float parameters?

(Also tried making a `Vector2.normalized` with the object's Rigidbody2D velocity and then using it to set them but they do not seem to be affected).

```
knightvector = (new Vector2(x, y)).normalized;
body.velocity = knightvector;
anim.SetFloat("x",knightvector.x);
anim.SetFloat("y",knightvector.y);
```

Any help?

Comment: you should update the parameters when the enemy moves (Update() method). You can set variables on the animator and set/access them on script.

Comment: I have done all these :/ I'll post my code in a while.